# Sorting string of numbers separated with ; in C#

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I have a string in the following format.

96354-3;38465-3;38465-1

Output should be

38465-1;38465-3;96354-3

I get the data in XML format and i convert it into above input string format.Here is the code i used

```
string _sample = string.Join(";",fd.Descendants("Field").fd.Descendants("Reference").Select(x=>x.Value))
```

Here Field is the root node and Reference is child node.

Please help me with sorting. Sorting need to be based on the number. Thank you

Comment: Thos are not normal ints. Are those Telephone Numbers? Exponential representation? | What have you tried? What is happening or not happening?

Comment: I can help you with some hints. There is a string.Split method that returns an array and then there is a string.Join method that could recreate a string from an array. Then https://zenpencils.com/comic/84-chinese-proverb-give-a-man-a-fish/#duplicate=0

Comment: Consider taking each character and placing it into an array then using an array.sort function

Answer (score 3):

Here is it:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "96354-3;38465-3;38465-1";
    string output = Sort(input);
    //output = 38465-1;38465-3;96354-3
}

private string Sort(string input)
{
    List<string> list = input.Split(';').ToList();
    list.Sort((x1,x2) => x1.CompareTo(x2));
    return string.Join(";", list.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is not working for the following criteria 107574-1;44244-3;44244-1. Sorting is based on the numbers in the string. Thank you.

Comment: ?? yes it works, I take you criteria "107574-1;44244-3;44244-1" and I have as output: 107574-1;44244-1;44244-3 (second element becomes the third)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by `OrderBy`

```
string input = "96354-3;38465-3;38465-1";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", input.Split(';').ToArray().OrderBy(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace("-","")))));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is not working for the following criteria 107574-1;44244-3;44244-1. Sorting is based on the numbers in the string. Thank you.

Comment: @shashi, have added conversion logic to sort by number